# Windows store xaml AppBarButton edit icon size

Tags: xaml, button, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

How do I edit the symbol size inside an AppBarButton? When I try to scale the AppBarButton or the SymbolIcon, it doesn't get scaled it just changes the surroundings dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the default style and template for the AppBarButton class? 
It's available at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481531.aspx

If you don't want to create your own AppBarButton style, you can try setting the AppBarButton.Content to a TextBlock and set the font-size.
fyi the margins in the AppBarButton default template are hard-coded so you may have to set the margins on your AppBarButton.Content's Textblock to have it centered the way you want.